# How to call derived class virtual method from base class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1()
  {
    init();
  }
  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init");
  }
}

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
public:
  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init");
  }
}

int main()
{
  MyClass2 *obj = new MyClass2();
  return 0;
}
```

I would like for this to result

```
"MyClass2 init"
```

But it show the message Actually

```
"MyClass1 init"
```

How to call derived class virtual method from base class constructor ?

=== update1 ===

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1()
  {
    init();
  }
  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init");
  }
}

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass2()
    : MyClass1()
  {
  }

  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init");
  }
}
```

I hope MyClass2 override MyClass1 init method
But it still show "MyClass1 init"

How C++ works like java/C# override method ?

=== update2 ===

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1()
  {
    init();   <--- can't work like test method ??? 
  }
  void test()
  {
    init();   <--- work fine
  }
  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init");
  }
}

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass2()
    : MyClass1()
  {
  }

  virtual void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init");
  }
}
```

I know obj->init() will call MyClass2::init. 
but I hope C++ can run in Constructor method.

Although obj->init() can be resolved. 
But I hope that the code can write a little less. 
Some people forget to call init().

Java/C# can Write less do more. But C++ can't.... This is very frustrating.

Comment: Calling virtual functions from your base class constructor isn't a very wise choice. Why can't you just call the derived `init` from the derived constructor?

Comment: Doing what you kinda kinda defeats the purpose of polymorphism.. The constructor of `MyClass2` will get called anyway, by the way.

Comment: You can't. The derived class doesn't exist yet to be called on.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290132/overriding-function-called-by-base-class/14290194#14290194

Comment: With `Qt` you can declare the function `Q_INVOKABLE` and do `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to call it when the constructor is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think: 
No reason C++ can not do java/C# virtual contructor mechanism.
I want to break the C++ rules. 
I also hope that C++ can write less to do more.
Would not progress if C++ does not improve, so that more people can not easily entry.

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1()
  {
    init();
  }

  typedef void (MyClass1::virtual_init)();
  MyClass1(virtual_init vinit)
  {
    (this->*vinit)();
  }

  //virtual void init()
  void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init");
  }
}

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass2()
    : MyClass1(&MyClass2::init)
  {
  }

  //virtual void init()
  void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer about how I solved this issue using CRTP.  I agree that it should be possible to call the derived class virtual function from constructor, but that is the way C++ works.  Perhaps future versions will have this feature.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly during the construction of `MyClass2`, `MyClass1`'s constructor will be called first, 
that's base class parts of derived class objects are constructed before derived class parts are. Even when you clearly try to create object of `MyClass2`, but during base class construction, virtual functions never go down into derived classes.

Because base class constructors execute before derived class constructors, derived class data members have not been initialized when base class constructors run. If virtual functions called during base class construction went down to derived classes, the derived class functions would almost certainly refer to local data members, but those data members would not yet have been initialized which will cause undefined behavior.

Refer to your classes, why do you have `virtual init` in the first place? Constructors should do the work respectively.

> How to call derived class virtual method from base class constructor ?

It's bad idea, should never ever do that!

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  virtual ~MyClass1() { }
  virtual void doSomething()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init");
  }
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
public:
  virtual void doSomething()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init");
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass1*obj = new MyClass2();
  obj->doSomething();
  delete obj;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mark base function virtual, overwrite it in derived class. then when you call: `MyClass1 *obj = new MyClass2(); obj->init();`, MyClass2::init will be called

Comment: I know obj->init() will call MyClass2::init. but I hope C++ can run in Constructor method.

Comment: C++ doesn't work that way. why do you want it? That' refers to design a proper C++ application.

Comment: Although obj->init() can be resolved.
But I hope that the code can write a little less.
Some people forget to call init().

Comment: yes, `obj->init()` is ok, but just not from base constructor!

Comment: example: std::string(char* str){ virtual copy(str) } This case, how to do?

Comment: `copy` doesn't need to be virtual at all :)

Comment: =.=  Sometimes have to do invoke virtual in constructor. 
example: class Image , class PngImage Copy(mem*), class BmpImage Copy(mem*)

Comment: A static version Copy will suffice

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you can't. That's because the `MyClass2` constructor has not yet been run, so if `MyClass2::init()` were to be called, any member variable would be uninitialized. Until this constructor is started the object, for virtual purposes, is considered to be a `MyClass1` instance.

For example:

```
class MyClass2 : public MyClass1
{
private:
    std::string xxx;
public:
    virtual void init()
    {
        xxx = "ops!"; //undefined if called from base class constructor
    }
};
```

The assignment to `xxx` will render undefined behavior, because its constructor has not yet been run.

Given your lack of ending `;` I'm guessing your background in Java/C#. These languages have implemented this issue differently, but that's just how C++ works.

Comment: But i hope C++ can override method, How C++ works like java/C# override method ?

Comment: @Flash: Of course it can. The difference is that in C++, if you call a virtual method from a constructor of the base class, then the call _will not_ be overriden. Once the object has been fully constructed the virtual method will work as expected. It works like this to protect you from errors like the one in my example code.

Comment: @Flash: These rules are there for a reason. If you don't like C++, by all means, do not use it. But if you use it, then you have to follow the rules. The fact that they are different than those on your favourite language doesn't make them "_less_", just "different".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is legal or would likely to break in future. But, using lambda function, you can send your code up to the base class to execute during constructor.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(std::function<void()> fnCall=nullptr) {
        if (fnCall) fnCall();
    }
    Base(const Base &base, std::function<void()> fnCall = nullptr) {
        DoSomethingAtBaseHere();
        if (fnCall) fnCall();
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(std::function<void()> fnCall=nullptr) : Base([&]() {
        DoSomethingAtDerivedHere();
        if (fnCall) fnCall();
    }) {}
    Derived(const Derived &oth, std::function<void()> fnCall=nullptr) : 
    Base(oth, [&]() {
        DoSomethingInCopyConstructorAtDerivedHere();
        if (fnCall) fnCall();
    })  {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I used [CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for solving this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define derived static_cast<T*>(this)

template<class T> // CRTP
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1()
  {
    derived->init();
  }
  void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass1 init\n");
  }
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1<MyClass2>
{
public:
  void init()
  {
    printf("MyClass2 init\n");
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass2 *obj2 = new MyClass2();
  return 0;
}
```

This program prints `MyClass2 init` as expected instead of `MyClass init`. If the function in derived class does not exist, it calls the parent class function.

Pros of CRTP:

- Function calls statically compiled
- Faster than Virtual functions
- Can control which method is called

Downsides of CRTP:

- Slightly less readable
- All functions called in derived class from parent class have to be `public`. The corresponding parent class functions also have to be public.
- Need to pass class name as template parameter

Comment: I think there are 2 extra demerits：1. If there is a Myclass3 which inherits from MyClass1<MyClass3>, Myclass3 and Myclass2 don't share the same base class. 2. Each template class will take individual code space which means when you have Myclass2~Myclass101, there will be 100 copies of Myclass1 in your code.

Comment: @NeNe About (1) If you are talking about instance of base class, then yes, but not sure if base class instance would be needed to be accessed in real life in such cases.
(2) This is a downside of templating and not just for CRTP.